# Create a URL to accept POST

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

can I just create just an aspx.vb file without the .aspx form and make it to accept POST url from other server in order to receive information.  Or, Do I have to create a Web form with code behind in aspx.vb ?  I only using Visual Basic.  Can I have a website's default page is .aspx.vb file?

Comment: you can use handlers

Comment: Can you send me a URL for development of this handlers? Would this is a good reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307997 ? Thx

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=mLcbVP31NpCAuAT92oD4Bw&gws_rd=ssl#q=ASP.NET+HTTP+Handler+in+vb.net